# Connect SQL developer with MYSQL server running on Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, oracle-sqldeveloper

Could you please guide me - How can I connect my local SQL developer to MY SQL Server running on Docker container.[image]

Comment: is the docker mysql image running? what is the output of `docker ps -a`? and is it running on the port 3306 or a different one?

Comment: Yes, the image is running and port no is 3306.

Comment: do you have the local port binded to the image port? (when you start your container you have a flag like `-p3306:3306`). if you have another mysql instance running on your real machine, you need to bind that to a different port (like `-p3307:3306`)

Comment: can I see the "docker run" command or docker-compose.yml... seems port is not binding , as @Alex says.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the "bind"in  my.cnf in docker running container, if its says 127.0.0.1 it will not connect from outside , you probably needs to change to 0.0.0.0 and restart the mysql server

Answer (score 0):

I have used this command to run container -> docker run -p 3306:3306 --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest

It solved that issue for me.